# Limit supremum question

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Suppose $(a_n)$ is a bounded sequence such that $\limsup_{n\to \infty} a_n \leq 2$ and $\sum_{k=1}^\infty b_k$ is a positive series that converges to 1. Show that

$$\limsup_{n\to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{a_k b_k}{n} \leq 2$$

My solution is as such:

Let $B_n = \sum_{k=1}^n b_k$. $B_n$ is monotone increasing since it is a positive series. Therefore, $B_n$ is $\leq 1$ for all n.

Using Abel's Lemma, $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{a_k b_k}{n} = (\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} B_k(\frac{a_k}{k} - \frac{a_{k+1}}{k+1})) + \frac{a_nB_n}{n} \leq  (\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} (\frac{a_k}{k} - \frac{a_{k+1}}{k+1})) + \frac{a_n}{n}$

This last summation is a telescope series, so

$(\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} (\frac{a_k}{k} - \frac{a_{k+1}}{k+1})) + \frac{a_n}{n} \leq a_1 - \frac{a_n}{n} + \frac{a_n}{n} = a_1 \leq \limsup_{n\to \infty} a_n \leq 2$.

Take lim sup both sides, then since 2 is a constant, we obtain the result.

Is this correct?

Comment: Are you trying to prove that $\limsup_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{a_kb_k}{n} \leq 2$. Because you forgot to include the RHS in your question.

Comment: oh ya sorry yup

Comment: How do you get $a_1 \leq \limsup_{n \to \infty} a_n $?

Answer (score 0):

The final step is incorrect since $a_1$ can be very large even if $\limsup$ is small. However you can do this:

$$ \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{a_k b_k}{n} \leq \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{a_k}{n} =  \frac{\sum_{k=1}^na_k}{n}$$

This is because as you pointed out, $b_k \leq 1$

The RHS is called the Cesaro sum of $a_k$. Now here are a few hints:

1. $\limsup_{n \to \infty} a_n \leq a$ means that

$\forall \epsilon >0, \quad \exists N, \forall k > N, \quad a_k \leq a+\epsilon$

For large enough n,

$$\frac{\sum_{k=1}^na_k}{n} = \frac{\sum_{k=1}^Na_k + \sum_{k=N+1}^na_k}{n} \leq \frac{\sum_{k=1}^Na_k + \sum_{k=N+1}^n(a+\epsilon)}{n}$$
$$ = \frac{\sum_{k=1}^Na_k}{n} + \frac{(n-N)(a+\epsilon)}{n} = \frac{\sum_{k=1}^Na_k}{n} + \left(1-\frac{N}{n}\right)(a+\epsilon)$$

Can you proceed from here?

Comment: i think the \epsilon is unnecessary right? i think removing it will make the proof cleaner. Am I right?

Comment: Well... It is a technicality. Don't remove it at the start. Instead after taking n to infinity argue that epsilon is arbitrary and hence remove it. Formally speaking, it is required since if you take $a_n = \frac{1}{n}$ and $a=0$, notice that $a_n$ is never $\leq 0$. However the $\limsup$ is.

Comment: do u know about the stolz theorem? Can I use it here? Because if I use it, i will get the lim sup summation above <= lim sup anbn and since an is bounded and bn tends to 0, it is again <= 0?